# dryscrape click "load more button"

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape www.ratemyprofessors.com and I need to click the "load more" button to scrape the all the data that i need. However, the code that im using right now isn't working

```
loadButton = session.at_xpath(path)
    loadButton.click()
```

The path is definitely correct since `loadButton.text()` equals "load more", however it gives me an error saying basically "failed to click because of overlapping element".

Does anyone know how to fix this or a workaround? from what i've been reading we can also simulate the function that javascript is running in the network tab. However i have some trouble finding the function since onclick doesn't directly call a function, but instead

```
onclick="javascript:mtvn.btg.Controller.sendLinkEvent({ linkName:\'PROFMIDPANE:LoadMore\', linkType:\'o\' } );
```

btw I am using python and the "load more" button is located on the left side under the list of professors after you perform a search for school

I've been reading some relevant posts but haven't come cross anything useful

Any help would be appreciated!

[my network/params tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeE6Q.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), when you click the load more button a request is made:

[image]

So once you have a page, you can get all the teachers and ratings in *json* format using the url http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=881718 below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


params = {"solrformat": "true",
          "rows": "1000", # set it high number to always get all rows.
          "q": "",
          "defType": "edismax",
          "qf": "teacherfullname_t^1000 autosuggest",
          "bf": "pow(total_number_of_ratings_i,2.1)",
          "sort": "total_number_of_ratings_i desc",
          "siteName": "rmp",
          "fl": "pk_id teacherfirstname_t teacherlastname_t total_number_of_ratings_i averageratingscore_rf schoolid_s"}

url = "http://search.mtvnservices.com/typeahead/suggest/"
query = '*:* AND schoolid_s:{id} AND teacherdepartment_s:"{subject}"'
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=881718").content)
    # pass the school id which we can parse from the page.
    params["q"] = query.format(id=soup.select_one("[data-schoolid]")["data-schoolid"], subject="History")
    res = s.get(url, params=params)

    json_data = res.json()


from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(json_data["response"]["docs"])
```

Gives us:

```
[{u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.6,
  u'pk_id': 1347824,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'JP',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Godwin',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 88},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.38,
  u'pk_id': 692471,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'James',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Page',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 49},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.5,
  u'pk_id': 555487,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Kevin',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Davis',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 44},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.4,
  u'pk_id': 1289399,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Jane',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'England',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 33},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.46,
  u'pk_id': 1230841,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Simone',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'De Santiago Ramos',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 24},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.15,
  u'pk_id': 701257,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Jack',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Pyle',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 23},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.13,
  u'pk_id': 1466455,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Chris',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Politz',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 20},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.67,
  u'pk_id': 1218949,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'James',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Hathcock',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 18},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.93,
  u'pk_id': 1648329,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Joshua',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Montandon',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 15},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 2.79,
  u'pk_id': 1543864,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'M',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Antle',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 14},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.83,
  u'pk_id': 1096585,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Scotty',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Edler',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 12},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.92,
  u'pk_id': 1260089,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'James',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Reynolds',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 12},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.42,
  u'pk_id': 1418409,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Steve',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Wolfrum',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 12},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.45,
  u'pk_id': 899881,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Karen',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Stewart',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 11},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.2,
  u'pk_id': 592508,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Crystal',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Wright',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 10},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.5,
  u'pk_id': 891457,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Lisa',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Morales',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 10},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 2.9,
  u'pk_id': 1329058,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Mark',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Thompson',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 10},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.0,
  u'pk_id': 1339373,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Charles',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Williams',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 10},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.5,
  u'pk_id': 1587880,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Noelle',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Depperschmidt',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 10},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.39,
  u'pk_id': 1426470,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Adrien',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Ivan',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 9},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 5.0,
  u'pk_id': 1871677,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Kevin',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Eades',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 9},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.81,
  u'pk_id': 393151,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Sharon',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Romero',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 8},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.69,
  u'pk_id': 1377603,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Joseph',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Ialenti',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 8},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.43,
  u'pk_id': 1752608,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'James',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Jones',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 7},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.43,
  u'pk_id': 1782369,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Sara',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Ruppel',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 7},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.33,
  u'pk_id': 1096000,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Scott',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Harp',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 6},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 2.17,
  u'pk_id': 2061535,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'David',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Powell',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 6},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.1,
  u'pk_id': 556560,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'English',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 5},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.9,
  u'pk_id': 2032232,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Robin',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Jett',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 5},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.3,
  u'pk_id': 1242893,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Dennis',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Spillman',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 5},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 5.0,
  u'pk_id': 1209837,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Jared',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Sutton',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 4},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.38,
  u'pk_id': 1587886,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Arianna',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Warren',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 4},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.4,
  u'pk_id': 1643053,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Kimberly',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Lacoco',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 4},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 2.5,
  u'pk_id': 1857299,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Kevin',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Pyle',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 4},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 2.33,
  u'pk_id': 892723,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Keith',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Mitchener',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 3},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.5,
  u'pk_id': 1448008,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Sally',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Stratso',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 3},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 3.25,
  u'pk_id': 680381,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Todd',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Venable',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 2},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 5.0,
  u'pk_id': 1256069,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Amanda',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Campbell-Wyatt',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 2},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 5.0,
  u'pk_id': 2142326,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Jeremy',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Godwin',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 2},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 1.5,
  u'pk_id': 697421,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Woody',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Paige',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 1},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 1.0,
  u'pk_id': 881718,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'M',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Sullivan',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 1},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 1.5,
  u'pk_id': 1607181,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Nancy',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Coffelt',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 1},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 5.0,
  u'pk_id': 1710114,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Jason',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Scheller',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 1},
 {u'averageratingscore_rf': 4.0,
  u'pk_id': 2164391,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'James',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Paige',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 1},
 {u'pk_id': 2083511,
  u'schoolid_s': u'4873',
  u'teacherfirstname_t': u'Stephen ',
  u'teacherlastname_t': u'Wolfrum',
  u'total_number_of_ratings_i': 0}]
```

All you need to so is pass the school id and the subject to the query string and you can get whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Can you explain a bit more on how you click the "load more" button with the request image that you posted?

I am guessing that 

`res = s.get(url, params=params)` is responsible for simulating clicking the button, so can you explain how you got the parameters based on the request image you posted?

Comment: @b.g, yes, go to developer tools, look under JS tab and click load more, you will see each time you do a request like what you see above is fired. If you pass `subject="Music"` etc.. you can see other results.

Comment: i am able to find the request for the button, but I am not sure how to use it
in my network tab i have different parameters than the params you use in your code (see my edit for my network/params tab). So i am just wondering how you got your params and use it to load more profs

Comment: @b.g, not sure how to use what?

Comment: lol sorry im new to stackoverflow and i kept using ENTER for new line. see the edit above

Comment: What are you looking at, the JS tab?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: firefox. which you did you use to get the params?

Comment: In Firefix it is under "All"

Comment: yeah i've tried the code. The loads doesn't work for me as i get `TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API`. but i printed out the content for res and it looks correct

Comment: oh i just looked under "all" and i found the params that matches yours. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, all you ever need is to manually input a subject and  the bs4 code will get the id, if you change  fl to   `"fl": "*"`, you might also find more interesting output. You don't need loads, just call `.json()` as above, I removed the callback parameter so now we just get valid json. Also change query to  `'*:* AND schoolid_s:{id}'` and that would give you every subject per school

Answer (score 0):

If the overlapping element is a banner or an overlay or something like that:

```
overlapping_element = session.at_xpath('//path_to_element')
overlapping_element.exec_script('node.parentElement.removeChild(node)')
loadButton.click()
```