# How to find a request URL for the data you are looking for?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm experiencing a similar problem as the guy from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065492/dryscrape-click-load-more-button) post. I want to create a function that takes the url of a professor at ratemyprofessor.com, and gets all the text from all the comments. By default though, the page only shows the first 20 comments, then you have to load more in, in bunches of 20s. Okay, so now, I need to create a function that loads comments in the maximum number of times and then gets the comment data. After looking through the post I referenced in my first sentence though, I realized I could actually just get all the comment from some request url.

I don't know much about making requests though, I've tried to connect the dots using the referenced post.  I've used chrome dev tools to try to look for calls involving comments, but I haven't been able to find the url to send the request to, or really what to pass to it to get what I want (all comments for a particular professor).

Instead of just asking for the answer, I'd like to generalize this post by also asking for best practices when trying to find a request url and getting the particular data you want from it.

**1. What is the Request URL I'm looking for?**

**2. How do I navigate getting my comment data?**

**3. What could I have done to discover this myself?**

I'm using python, bs4 and requests, as recommended by the referenced post.

----- Edit -----

I'm sorry if I was unclear, I know how to parse HTML with bs4. Here is my code:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=433738").content)
    yes = soup.find_all('p','commentsParagraph')
```

The variable `yes` contains all the comments on the page, which is good, but not all of what I want. There is a script that builds and formats all the comment blocks, and passes comments into the block. These comments are requested from somewhere, and I believe (based on the referenced post) that I can send a request to that address, and get all the comments. I'm asking for the address, and the code (possible query of sorts) that goes along with it to get all the comments.

Comment: There is absolutely no way to answer this question. The URL to get the data for a particular site will depend entirely on how that site is written.

Comment: @Padraic_Cunningham  I'd appreciate it if you could take a look at my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "http://example.com" 
#var that stores url 
 
request_it = requests.get(url).text 
#using the .get method from the requests module to get the page 

soup = BeautifulSoup(request_it, 'html.parser') 
# args ( the html markup, parser ) as parser most common : html.parser, lxml
table = soup.find('table') 
#this will for example find one table tag and includes all tags within
one_tablerow = table.find('tr')
# it will find only one table row, we can use .findAll('tr') if we want ALL
print(one_tablerow.text) #This will only print the text, sometimes we use .string if error
```

The basics:

1. Use requests module to download the HTML-markup of the page
2. Use BeautifulSoup to go through tags and get certain elements

   a) The most common practice is to go through the tree example:
   `soup.find('tag').h.p.a.text` for instance this will first find 'tag' then the `.h` tag within then the child of that `.p` then the child of that tag `.a` e.g. `<a href>` and then extract the text from that tag.

It's also important to know the basics of **HTML** like the tree terminology and tags, root, child and parent.

One more thing, this is a broad question, you said you're using these modules that you mentioned e.g. `requests, BeautifulSoup` but you're not really using them since you're asking these questions, therefore, I'd highly suggest that you at least watch 1hour of content of each since that is easier than going through docs. However, I posted because I'm hoping that this code can get you acquainted at least with the terminology and when you run this code that you'll be exploring, more...